# How to change full URL in address bar without reloading page?

Tags: javascript

Current URL: `"www.example.com/dashboard/test"`

I want to change: `"www.example.com/task/5"`

I've tried:

```
var browserState = {Url: "www.example.com/task/5" };
history.pushState(browserState, "", browserState.Url);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#examples

I've seen many example. But all where, just changed the parameter. But I want to change the full url.
Please someone help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can. It's a security mechanism, because phishing sites could use it to make you think you're at the real site.

Comment: Hi John. FIrstly, why do you want to change the full URL? What event triggers that on your case?

Comment: @DhanaD. Hi. I've a modal in my website. But when I open the bootstrap modal, it can't change the url. But I want to copy the url when open the modal. That's why I've to change the url. Have any way?

Comment: @Barmar Hmm understand. But have any way?

Comment: If there were a way, I wouldn't have written "I don't think you can".

Comment: You can't do this. Can you imagine the madness that would unleash if you could? I could have you believe you are on one site, when you are in fact on another!

Comment: @Barmar I've edit the question details. Please check now.

Comment: I haven't tried the below code. but you can give it a try
     `const url = '/task/'+id;
     const state = { 'id': id }
     const title = ''
     history.pushState(state, title, url);`

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is not practically possible.

If you want to change a url that will always redirect to the website.

You can embed the website if you want to stay in the same website. You can use iframe

Comment: This will redirect to the URL, not just change what shows in the location bar.

Comment: If you change the url it will automatically redirect.

Comment: @moshfiqrony I don't want to reload the page.

Comment: See. If you change the url from one domain to another domain. It will reload. Think like this, say you are in a house which address is 162/A, now you went to 167/A. So practically changing the address will always change the house. If this would be possible then phishing would be so easy for hacker.

Comment: Now if you want to display that website but not leaving the main website. You have to embed it in a iframe. Like you can embed YouTube video. In your website.